# Variance expressed in Quadratic Form

Tags: variance, matrix

Given a vector $\pmb x$ of length $n$, $\pmb x=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ the variance is proportional to

$\pmb x^\top \pmb x - \frac{1}{n}{\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)}^2$

I'm trying to determine $(i,j)$ position of $Q$ when expressed in quadratic form

$\tfrac{1}{2} \mathbf{x}^\top Q\mathbf{x} $

however, the cross-terms in the summation is getting me confused.

**EDIT**

Solved it.
(Edit: User603 had correct solution earlier, below; accepted answer)
 (ignoring the 1/2 term)

```
n=10;
x=randi(100,n,1); % arbitrary vector of data
Q=(1/n)*(n*eye(n)-ones(n));
v1=(n-1)*var(x)
v2=x'*x - (1/n)*(sum(x))^2
v3=x'*Q*x
```

v1, v2, and v3 all equal. For Q, on-diagonals are $1-\frac{1}{n}$ and off-diagonals are $-\frac{1}{n}$

Comment: The variance of a vector of *numbers* is a *number*, not a matrix.  If the $x_i$ are intended to represent random variables, then the first formula you give is a random variable--but it's not a variance (or covariance).  Please clarify.

Comment: Correct, we want a number. If given a set of elements as a column vector $x$, the first formula is proportional to var(x). X could be [1,2,3,4,5]' or [10, 100, 200]. We are trying to determine the expression of Q such that the second formula equals the first. Specifically, how to determine the (i,j)th element of Q as a function of i, j, and X.

Comment: I see where you're coming from, @user603, and will vote to re-open.  Thank you for your comment!

Comment: My apologies. Was confused on the notation on the subscript in Q. Yes, you solved it exactly how I was thinking. Will accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, to make this short, I need to use the following (classical in optimisation) notations:

$$\pmb Q_{\pmb A}(\pmb x):=\pmb x^\top \pmb A \pmb x$$

then $\pmb 1_{n\times n}$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix of ones and denote as $\pmb I_{n\times n}$  the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix. Then:

$$\pmb Q_{\pmb I_{n\times n}-\frac{1}{n}\pmb 1_{n\times n}}(\pmb x)=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^2-\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\right)^2$$

which is a number proportional to the variance of $\pmb x$.